# Add a class to a grandparent's child img

Tags: jquery, class, parent

I have some images with checkboxes. When I check one of them, image should change through the new class "change-img".
Here is a code:

```
<ul>
    <li class="tech-vis"><img class="tech-img" src="..." alt="..."/></li>
    <li class="check-tech"><input id="const-tech" class="checkbox-form inside"  type="checkbox" name="tech[]" value="value1" /></li>                                                    
</ul>
<ul>
    <li class="tech-vis"><img class="tech-img" src="..." alt="..."/></li>
    <li class="check-tech"><input id="const-tech" class="checkbox-form inside"  type="checkbox" name="tech[]" value="value2" /></li>                                                    
</ul>
... and etc.
```

And a script:

```
$("ul input[type=checkbox].inside").click(function() {
    if($(this).is(":checked")) {
        $(this).parents("ul img.tech-img").addClass("change-img");
    }
    else {
        $("img.tech-img").removeClass("change-img")
    }
});
```

I know that I'm wrong in line, where I'm adding a class, but how can I call this element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **[`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** or **[`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents/)** by separating the parent `ul` from the child `img`, like :

```
$(this).closest("ul").find('img.tech-img').addClass("change-img");
//Or
$(this).parents("ul").find('img.tech-img').addClass("change-img");
```

**NOTE :** Be careful the `id` should be unique in the same document.

Hope this helps.

```js
$("ul input[type=checkbox].inside").click(function() {
  var parent = $(this).parents("ul");

  if($(this).is(":checked")) {
    parent.find('img.tech-img').addClass("change-img");
  }
  else {
    //Remove class from all img tags
    $("img.tech-img").removeClass("change-img"); 

    //Remove class from related img tag
    //parent.find('img.tech-img').removeClass("change-img"); 
  }
});
```

```css
.change-img{
   background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="tech-vis"><img class="tech-img" src="http://hytorcatlantique.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/android-icon.png" alt="..."/></li>
  <li class="check-tech"><input id="const-tech1" class="checkbox-form inside"  type="checkbox" name="tech[]" value="value1" /></li>                                                    
</ul>
<ul>
  <li class="tech-vis"><img class="tech-img" src="http://hytorcatlantique.fr/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/android-icon.png" alt="..."/></li>
  <li class="check-tech"><input id="const-tech2" class="checkbox-form inside"  type="checkbox" name="tech[]" value="value2" /></li>                                                    
</ul>
```

Comment: @Tesla an other suggestion is that don't use same ids for multiple elements. It can cause you issues with javascript interaction.

Comment: Yes, it worked. I know about unique id's, but thank you anyway. Closest() and find() solved my problem. Thank you a lot!